# About a relation between isometries

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If we have $(T_i)_{i=1}^N$, operators on a Hilbert space, that are also isometries and satisfy the following relation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^NT_iT_i^*=Id\quad (1)$$

How can you prove that they must also verify $T_i^*T_j=\delta_{i,j}Id\quad (2)$ ?

---

I think that the operators $T_i$ verify $T_i^*T_i=Id$ directly just because they are isometries. But how to prove that $T_i^*T_j=0$ for $i\neq j$?

Comment: Is it possible that $T_i^* T_j = 0$? An isometry $S$ satisfies $\|S v \| = \|v\|$ for all $v \in H$, and $S^*$ is an isometry iff $S$ is. Hence $\| T_i^* T_j v \| = \| T_j v \| = \| v \|$ for all $v \in H$. But this contradicts that $T_i^* T_j = 0$. Additionally, isometries satisfy $S S^* = I$, so I don't think it's possible that $\sum_i T_i T_i^* = I$.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, and why I am confused. But the question comes from the relations known as cuntz relations.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuntz_algebra In a book I saw a proposed question where it says that relation 1 + the fact that $(T_i)_i $are isometries gives automatically relation 2.

Comment: The book I was checking out, where the proposed question comes from is "Analysis and Probability wavelets, signals, fractals" by Jorgensen. The question can be found in page 174, it's the 8,2.

Comment: I removed the "matrices" tag. The Cuntz relations are impossible in finite dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that we may assume that all $T_k$ are proper isometries; because if one of them, say $T_1$, is a unitary, we get $\sum_{k=2}^NT_kT_k^*=0$, which forces $T_k=0$ for all $k\geq2$.

Since $\sigma(T_k^*T_k)=\sigma(I)=\{1\}$, using that $\sigma(AB)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(BA)\cup\{0\}$ we deduce that $\sigma(T_kT_k^*)=\{0,1\}$ (the zero has to be there because otherwise $T_k$ is a unitary). It follows that $P_k=T_kT_k^*$ is a projection. The question is now whether these projections are pairwise orthogonal.

Fix indices $i$ and $j$ with $i\ne j$. The argument below only uses $$\sum_{k=1}^NP_k\leq I,$$which we write as $$\sum_{k\ne i}P_k\leq I-P_i.$$ Then
$$
0\leq P_iP_jP_i\leq P_i\left(\sum_{k\ne i} P_k\right)P_i\leq P_i(I-P_i)P_i=0.
$$
So $P_iP_jP_i=0$. But then
$$
0=P_iP_jP_i=P_iP_j^2P_i=(P_jP_i)^*P_jP_i,
$$
and this implies that $P_jP_i=0$.

This is $T_jT_j^*T_iT_i^*=0$. Multiplying by $T_j^*$ on the left and by $T_i $ on the right, we get $T_j^*T_i=0$.

Comment: This question might be silly, but what is the meaning for you of  $\leq$ when operators are involved?

Comment: $A\leq B$ means $B-A\geq0$. In  Jorgensen's book, "positive" is defined in 7.3.1. After a quick look at the book, I don't think it gives you elements to deal with these kinds of questions. It mentions operators on a Hilbert space and with C$^*$-algebras, but it doesn't seem to give you even the most basic tools to deal with them.